# Having a problem with inserting a row into a sql database from an HTML form. What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly new at this

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my php file. Our instructor had us enter the function this way.  We initially had the function on a separate page that we were calling into the php file but I saw no reason to have it included that way.

```
<?php
function insertFlight($flights)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `flights` (`FlyingFrom`, `FlyingTo`, `DepartureDate`, `ReturnDate`, `TravelClass`, `Adults`, `Children`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', NULL)";
    $dbh = mysqli_connect("localhost", "fred", "password", "travelexperts");
    if (! $dbh)
    {
        die ("Error: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . " - " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbh, $sql);
    if (! $stmt)
    {
        die ("Error: " . mysqli_error($dbh));
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssii", $flights['FlyingFrom'], $flights['FlyingTo'], $flights['DepartureDate'], $flights['ReturnDate'], $flights['TravelClass'], $flights['Adults'], $flights['Children']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (mysqli_error($dbh))
    {
        print("Statement has an error: " . mysqli_error());
    }
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt))
    {
        mysqli_close($dbh);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_close($dbh);
        return false;
    }
}   
?>
```

Here is my html file. There are a few external files that I didn't include as they run correctly. I'm really just trying to figure out why the insert command is not working. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Flights</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\flightstyle.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Felipa" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
            color: #555753; 
            background: #fff url(http://csszengarden.com/001/blossoms.jpg) no-repeat bottom right; 
            }   

            p {
                font-family: 'Felipa', cursive;
                color: white;
                }
            h1 {
                margin-left: 480px;
                color: pink;
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>        
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#clock').fadeIn(1500).delay(2500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#picTwo').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
            });

        </script>

        <img src="images\fallingPetals.gif" id="clock" style="width:400px;height:300px;" /><br /><br /> <br />          
        <div id="booking" class="section">
            <div class="section-center">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="booking-form">
                            <div class="form-header">
                                <h1>Book Your Flight</h1>
                                <p>Embark on Your Journey.</p>
                                <img src="images\fallingpetalsrevers.gif" id="integrate" style="width:100px;height:70px;" />
                            </div>
                            <form method="post" action="tryme.php">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="FlyingFrom" required="required" type="text">
                                    <span class="form-label">Flying from</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="FlyingTo" required="required" type="text">
                                    <span class="form-label">Flying to</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="DepartureDate" required="required" type="date">
                                            <span class="form-label">Departure Date</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="ReturnDate" required="required" type="date">
                                            <span class="form-label">Return Date</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" name="TravelClass">
                                                <option>Economy class</option>
                                                <option>Business class</option>
                                                <option>First class</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                                            <span class="form-label">Travel class</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" name="Adults">
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                                <option>3</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                                            <span class="form-label">Adults</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" name="Children">
                                                <option>0</option>
                                                <option>1</option>
                                                <option>2</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                                            <span class="form-label">Children</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-btn">
                                    <button class="submit-btn">Book</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            $('.form-control').each(function () {
                floatedLabel($(this));
            });

            $('.form-control').on('input', function () {
                floatedLabel($(this));
            });

            function floatedLabel(input) {
                var $field = input.closest('.form-group');
                if (input.val()) {
                    $field.addClass('input-not-empty');
                } else {
                    $field.removeClass('input-not-empty');
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: When do you call `insertFlight`? `$sql` should have placeholders in it, not empty strings. You need the link in all `mysqli_error` calls (as you've done in almost all instances, except where you output it)

Comment: can you please explain where I would call that?   and are you saying I should not have the "VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', NULL)";?

Comment: Every `''` should be a `?`. Functions aren't executed unless they are called. If you never do `insertFlight();` that function won't execute. I'm guessing you want something like `insertFlight($_POST);`... or you could just remove the function definition and have it execute procedurally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement needs to have placeholders that your statement bind function fills in. Below is a simplified [example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
mysqli_stmt_execute();
```

Comment: `mysqli_prepare `, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, and `mysqli_stmt_execute` calls are incorrect here... the SQL is correct though.

Comment: I'm using the nomenclature of the OP, it's not my preferred choice, but it's not incorrect, merely the procedural style of the OO class/methods.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  it worked!    I had another php page, which needed to be included as that one was calling in the function.  Also, I inserted the ?'s .   success!    I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @VinceD Accept the answer or delete the question